# How to calculate distance from a GPX file?

Tags: xml, algorithm, gps, gpx

I have a [GPX file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPX_(data_transfer)) with a GPS track. Now I want to calculate the distance I covered with this track.

What's the best way to calculate this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The traditional way of calculating the distance between two points (each pair of waypoints in your GPX file) is with the Haversine formula.

I have a SQL Server function that implements the algorithm. This should be easy to translate into other languages:

```sql
create function dbo.udf_Haversine(@lat1 float, @long1 float, 
                   @lat2 float, @long2 float) returns float begin
    declare @dlon float, @dlat float, @rlat1 float, 
                 @rlat2 float, @rlong1 float, @rlong2 float, 
                 @a float, @c float, @R float, @d float, @DtoR float
    
    select @DtoR = 0.017453293
    select @R = 3959      -- Earth radius
    
    select 
        @rlat1 = @lat1 * @DtoR,
        @rlong1 = @long1 * @DtoR,
        @rlat2 = @lat2 * @DtoR,
        @rlong2 = @long2 * @DtoR
    
    select 
        @dlon = @rlong1 - @rlong2,
        @dlat = @rlat1 - @rlat2
    
    select @a = power(sin(@dlat/2), 2) + cos(@rlat1) * 
                     cos(@rlat2) * power(sin(@dlon/2), 2)
    select @c = 2 * atn2(sqrt(@a), sqrt(1-@a))
    select @d = @R * @c
    
    return @d 
end
```

This returns the distance in Miles. For kilometers, replace the earth radius with it's km equivalent.

[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180705004706/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/51879.html) is a more in-depth explanation.

Edit: This function is fast enough and accurate enough for doing radius searches with a ZIP code database. It has been doing a great job on [this site](http://kofc.org/un/findCouncil/index.action) for years (but it no longer does, as the link is broken now).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will port it to java and post it here. What does @DtoR means? Distance to Radius?

Comment: That's the factor that converts degrees into Radians, pi/180.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will post my Java version soon

Comment: The method is great for simple calculations, but it assumes the Earth is spherical. A more accurate calculation should use the WGS 84 ellipsoid standard or similar.

Answer (score 1):

[Mike Gavaghan has an algorithm](http://www.gavaghan.org/blog/free-source-code/geodesy-library-vincentys-formula/) for distance calculations on his site. There is a C# and also a JAVA version of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Delphi implementation of the [Vincenty formulae](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-vincenty.html)  can be found [here](http://www.programmersheaven.com/download/48584/19/ZipView.aspx).

Comment: @Adam Carter: I've checked the URL and it's still OK.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Scala implementation.

3958.761 is the [mean radius of the Earth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_radius#Mean_radii) in miles. To get a result in km (or some other unit) just alter this number.

```scala
// The Haversine formula
def haversineDistance(pointA: (Double, Double), pointB: (Double, Double)): Double = {
  val deltaLat = math.toRadians(pointB._1 - pointA._1)
  val deltaLong = math.toRadians(pointB._2 - pointA._2)
  val a = math.pow(math.sin(deltaLat / 2), 2) + math.cos(math.toRadians(pointA._1)) * math.cos(math.toRadians(pointB._1)) * math.pow(math.sin(deltaLong / 2), 2)
  val greatCircleDistance = 2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(a), math.sqrt(1 - a))
  3958.761 * greatCircleDistance
}

// A sequence of gpx trackpoint lat,long pairs parsed from the track GPX data
val trkpts: Seq[(Double, Double)] = {
  val x = scala.xml.XML.loadString(track)
  (x \\ "trkpt").map(trkpt => ((trkpt \ "@lat").text.toDouble, (trkpt \ "@lon").text.toDouble))
}

// Distance of track in miles using Haversine formula
val trackDistance: Double = {
  trkpts match {
    case head :: tail => tail.foldLeft(head, 0.0)((accum, elem) => (elem, accum._2 + haversineDistance(accum._1, elem)))._2
    case Nil => 0.0
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is rather old, but I would like to add a python option for completeness. [GeoPy](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/1.11.0/#module-geopy.distance) has both `great-circle distance` and `Vincenty distance`.