# calculate all latitude and longitudes in a metric area

Tags: sql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, distance

I know there are many threads about calculating from lat/long to metric systems. This solves the first part of my problem.

The second (main part) of my problem is this:

- I have google maps as map app.
- I have a lat&long pair of a point
- I have a a metric distance, lets say 30meters.
- I need some point to do a **sql query**.

Why?

I have many records of POIs which can be located with this lat&long pair. I don't want to get all the results (reason: better performance).

Is there a way to do something like:

```
select * from myTable where lat> .... and lat < ... and long > ... and long < ...?
```

Is this possible? And if its, how do I get these values in `...` ?

Regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the article: [Selecting points within a bounding circle](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-db.html)

and the SO question: [SQL Query for Performing Radius Search based on Latitude Longitude](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1727137/1314132)

These should get you started.

Comment: Ok that looks very similar to my problem. (But the solution is not that pretty.. :-D) anyways. thanks! +1

Answer (score 1):

here is a sample query that returns the distances between a supplier lat/lng and a database of lat/lng pairs:

```
DECLARE
@Latitude float,
@Longitude float

SET @Latitude = 46.51257000000000
SET @Longitude = -84.33660900000000

DECLARE @SampleData TABLE
(
Name varchar(100),
Lat float,
Lng float
)

INSERT INTO @SampleData
(Name, Lat, Lng)
SELECT 'Point1', 46.52450048415351,-84.35223018530274
UNION
SELECT 'Point2', 46.51835838382206,-84.30279170874024
UNION
SELECT 'Point3', 46.522138220045285,-84.2622796237793
UNION
SELECT 'Point4', 46.54056115608927,-84.223140829834

SELECT 
    Name,
    Lat,
    Lng,
    -- using spherical law of cosines, where 6371 is the earth's radius in km. Returns km.
    Distance = ACOS(SIN(RADIANS(@Latitude))*SIN(RADIANS(Lat))+COS(RADIANS(@Latitude))*COS(RADIANS(Lat))*COS(RADIANS(Lng-@Longitude)))*6371  
FROM 
    @SampleData
```