# Returning results within Latitude / Longitude rectagle

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, google-maps

Here is an example of my table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Addresses] (
[Id] int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) ,
[Latitude] float(53) NULL,
[Longitude] float(53) NULL
)
```

From our application I am getting back 2 sets of Latitude and Logitude Points in a bounding box format:

```
{"upperright":[32.91052662576775,-79.5290690551758],"lowerleft":[32.6420709033305,-80.33313094482423]}
```

So, based on what comes back in the bounding box results, I need to pass that information to an SQL query to find all of the addresses that are within that rectangle.

Comment: Here's a start: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895265(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Query for Performing Radius Search based on Latitude Longitude](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727137/sql-query-for-performing-radius-search-based-on-latitude-longitude)

Comment: @geocodezip, I am searching by Lat/Long, not zipcode

Comment: The query in that post determines the distance from the Latitude/longitude of a zipcode to the latitude/longitude of locations and returns those within the specified radius.  Isn't that what you are trying to do?

Comment: @geocodezip, I am not getting the values from a zip code. I need to find the locations, in my DB,  within that rectangle. I don;t see how this is a duplciate

Comment: See [Haversine function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula)

Comment: @geocodezip, I assumed you were talking about the first answer that was related to zip codes. That did not help me. The answer with searching based on min and max values helped. What upsets me here is I put that into my original question and nobody responded.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
Select * from Addresses
Where Addresses.Longitude between -80.33313094482423 and  -79.5290690551758
And Addresses.Latitude between 32.6420709033305 and 32.91052662576775
```

Comment: This doesn't account for the fact that you may be looking for a place between a latitude of 359.2 and 0.12. If given those parameters it would return all places that are in the opposite range of what you wanted

Answer (score 0):

To get The Duplicate Latitude and Longitude

```
WITH Dup_LatLong AS
(
SELECT row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY
LATITUDE, LONGITUDE ORDER BY Rpropid1) AS RowNumber, UniqueValue, convert(Varchar(50),LATITUDE)+convert(Varchar(50),LONGITUDE) Check_Cond
FROM YourTable)
Select UniqueValue,LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, convert(Varchar(50),LATITUDE)+convert(Varchar(50),LONGITUDE)
from YourTable
where convert(Varchar(50),LATITUDE)+convert(Varchar(50),LONGITUDE) in (Select Check_Cond from Dup_LatLong where RowNumber > 1)
order by 7
```