# Get logs within a given radius with MySql or Postgres

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, geolocation, postgis

I have the following table, where the latitude and longitude fields specify a point on the map.

```
|id   |latitud         |longitud         |
| --- | ------ --------| ---------------- | 
| 001 |19.4400570537131|-99.1270470974249 | 
| 002 |19.437904276995 |-99.1286576775023 |
| 003 |19.4360705910348|-99.1297865731994 |
| 001 |19.4424869116657|-99.1238332599196 |
```

I need to make a query that returns me the number of records that are around the point (19.4400570537131, -99.1270470974249) in a radius of 1000 meters.

If it is not possible with MySQL, I can use PostgreSQL

Comment: [st_distance_sphere](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-convenience-functions.html)

Comment: What are the units of your latitud (194400570537131) and longitud (-991270470974249 ) values? Please [edit] your question. They don't look like decimal degrees or some sort of UTM coordinate system. In the meantime [here is a writeup](https://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/haversine-mysql-nearest-loc/) on the general problem.

Comment: I had omitted the comma. Thank you very much for the appreciation

Comment: It seems that this question has already been answered here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727137/sql-query-for-performing-radius-search-based-on-latitude-longitude; and here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31628/find-features-within-given-coordinates-and-distance-using-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PostgreSQL (with PostGIS) the function you're looking for is called [`ST_DWithin`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html). To use it with metres you either have to [`ST_Transform`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Transform.html) your coordinates to a [`SRS`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_reference_system) that has metre as unit or use `geography` instead of `geometry`. The example below creates a point with [`ST_MakePoint`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePoint.html) in query time, cast it to `geography` and applies the filter with `ST_DWithin` and the point mentioned in your question within a radius of 1000 metres.

```
WITH j (id,lat,lon) AS ( VALUES
  (001,19.4400570537131,-99.1270470974249),
  (002,19.437904276995 ,-99.1286576775023),
  (003,19.4360705910348,-99.1297865731994),
  (001,19.4424869116657,-99.1238332599196)
) 
SELECT 
  id,
  ST_Distance(
    ST_MakePoint(lon,lat)::geography,
    ST_MakePoint(-99.1270470974249,19.4400570537131)::geography) AS distance,
  ST_MakePoint(lon,lat)::geography AS geom
FROM j 
WHERE ST_DWithin(
        ST_MakePoint(lon,lat)::geography,
        ST_MakePoint(-99.1270470974249,19.4400570537131)::geography,1000);

 id |   distance   |                        geom                        
----+--------------+----------------------------------------------------
  1 |            0 | 0101000020E6100000781F268A21C858C067123E94A7703340
  2 | 292.22521599 | 0101000020E61000001C5069ED3BC858C0D878A47E1A703340
  3 |   526.781174 | 0101000020E61000007CD6576C4EC858C0EA3D7F52A26F3340
  1 |  431.5655003 | 0101000020E6100000C16056E2ECC758C021837ED246713340
```

[image]

**Note**: I strongly suggest you to store these points in a `geometry` or `geography` column, and to properly index them. Creating geometries out of separated latitude and longitude values in query time creates an unnecessary overhead, and it might slow down your queries significantly. Also, in case you're not working in the microscopy realm, consider reducing the precision of your points ;)

Further reading:

- [`ST_Distance`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html)
- [`Measuring accuracy of latitude and longitude`](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/8674)
- [`Getting all Buildings in range of 5 miles from specified coordinates`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51889638/2275388)