# Get nearby locations from database having lat and lan

Tags: android, ios, location, core-location, latitude-longitude

I have a database with thousands of users having latitude and longitude values, I want to get all users from database who are within 1 km radius around my current location.

say I am at location A with my lat 10 and long 20. I have to search users nearby with the range of 1 km.... and these user locations are stored in database.

one way I figured out to get each user lat and lon and compare with mine with iOS method `distanceFromLocation:` but that requires each value to be fetched first and then calculated with method..Is there any other way ? Maybe to do this on database side?

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate it from mysql.

For total description how to do it http://www.scribd.com/doc/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL

For quick answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/570048/2246798

Or this https://stackoverflow.com/a/574736/2246798

**EDIT**

Please find the code here

*ACTUAL TABLE*

[image: Demo table]

*QUERY WITH RESPONSE*

[image: Query with response]

Comment: Hi Thanks! the last stackoverflow answer seems fine.. but into this is there any column is distance bcz i m using sql server and its giving me error

Comment: Please check the full query. Specially  `( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) 
* cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin(radians(lat)) ) ) AS distance `